# How can I best convert an integer to a floating point value without assigning to a variable?

Tags: delphi

I would like to know how to convert from an integer to a floating point value, without assigning to an intermediate variable. The code in question looks like this:

```
Format('Theoretical peak scaling %6.2f', [ThreadCount])
```

This obviously fails at runtime because `ThreadCount` is an integer.

I tried the obvious

```
Format('Theoretical peak scaling %6.2f', [Double(ThreadCount)])
```

and the compiler rejects that with

```
E2089 Invalid typecast
```

I know I can write

```
Format('Theoretical peak scaling %6.2f', [ThreadCount*1.0])
```

but that reads poorly and will just tempt a future maintainer to remove the multiplication in error.

Does anyone know of a clean way to do this without an intermediate variable, and in way that makes the codes intent clear to future readers?

Comment: Just to be curious, why don't you want to use a variable?

Comment: @Toon Because I have to name it. So now I've got two local variables with essentially the same name, and the same value. The code will read better without the variable.

Comment: I prefer to use intermediate values. If the list is getting too long, it is time to split the function.  But the naming issue is also worth thinking about.

Comment: By keeping the list of local variables down, I can put off splitting the function. Splitting the function has costs too. Too many functions can be as bad a problem as too few. Although it's very rare to find yourself in that position.

Comment: I have still nightmares of C code with 9000 line functions.

Comment: FWIW, multiplying by 1.0 is such a long-standing idiom to produce a float that anybody who deletes such code as redundant should be fired.

Comment: Sadly, Delphi has never really had a clear syntactic distinction between type conversion and type casting. The form `someType(someVariable)` sometimes means one, sometimes the other. So (as of Delphi 2007 at least) you can't e.g. typecast an int64 into a COMP, presumably because the compiler thinks you want to do a conversion that isn't supported.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: 'ThreadCount', 'ConvertedThreadCount'. FAR MORE READABLE IMO than doing something funky in the format call. Also, mistake IMO to be concerned about a necessary variable that may actually be more efficient than doing something funky in the call to format. In modern systems, adding one extra variable for the sake of clarity and sometimes also efficiency is a no-brainer. Obviously there is a limit - if you need to declare more than 2 or 3 variables or parameters, refactoring is probably in order.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: ' tempt a future maintainer to remove the multiplication in error.' . Solution: add comment - // DO NOT DELETE - this is necessary for format to work. DH .... :-)

Comment: Imo the real problem in this case is not type conversion but the fact that %f and %n just except floats and refuse ordinal values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's academic and I'd use a function or * 1.0 but this works

```
Format('Theoretical peak scaling %6.2f', [Double(Variant(ThreadCount))])
```

Comment: mine , too ... I would never use it.

Comment: I'd use `+ 0.0` - generally addition is easier than multiplication :-D

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - you know, you could always make `1.0` a typed constant (call it `const 1.0 = INT_TO_FLOAT` and do `ThreadCount*INT_TO_FLOAT`.  That maybe adds a bit of elegance to the simple idomatic approach?

Answer (score 9):

This maybe feels silly... but if it's an integer why not just :

```
Format('Theoretical peak scaling %3d.00', [ThreadCount]);
```

It's not like you're ever going to have anything but zeroes after the decimal point, right?

Comment: dang it. i need to type faster. :P

Comment: Yeah, that gets that problem solved, but it doesn't actually convert to float. And in other situations I would imagine I'd want to convert.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ...other situations?

Comment: @J... Yes other situations. Other code which has an integer, needs to make a float, and isn't pass to `Format`. I'm thinking generally.

Comment: Of course this doesn't allow me to line up the decimal point. In my original version I had %6.2f. Here you could use %3d.00 but that will pad with zeros. So, again a true conversion to float would be the cleanest way around that.

Comment: `%3d` will pad with spaces, not zeroes.  You may be thinking of `%.3d`, which will pad with zeroes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm having trouble thinking what "other situations"  this would be an issue. The cast from integer to float is normally automatic.  In this case the format string is parsed at runtime so the compiler can't make the adjustment.

Comment: @Mark I guess it's because the second argument to Format is untyped. But yes, there don't seem to be many other scenarios.

Comment: @Mark Another situation: add thousand separators, e.g. `Format('Generate %.0n numbers in %.0n msec', [Count, Ticks])`

Answer (score 5):

You have the alternative to use a `record helper` for intrinsic types:

```
type
  TIntHelper = record helper for Integer
    function AsFloat : Double;
  end;

function TIntHelper.AsFloat: Double;
begin
  Result := Self;
end;

Format('Theoretical peak scaling %6.2f', [ThreadCount.AsFloat])
```

This was added in XE3, but with some restrictions from Embarcadero.
Since only one helper can be in scope, Emarcadero suggests that this feature is for them to use inside the RTL only.

Quote from Marco Cantu:

> - we advise against writing your own (although you might want to do this 
>     as a temporary measure for types we don't support)
> - the reason is not just the one helper per class rule, but also that 
>     this behavior change in the future, with different compiler mechanism. 
>     so if you got for this, don't hold your breath for the future.

Reference: [`On Record/Class/Type Helpers`](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=84839).

**Update:** In [`XE4`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE4#Run-Time_Library_.28RTL.29_Changes_for_XE4), a built-in helper class for integers, [`TIntegerHelper`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.SysUtils.TIntegerHelper), has a method `ToDouble`.

---

Using `RTTI` it can be solved like this with built in language elements:

```
Format('Theoretical peak scaling %6.2f', 
  [TValue.From<Integer>(ThreadCount).AsExtended])
```

---

Just FTR, a benchmark shows that `Double(Variant(i))` and inlined helper `i.AsFloat` are comparable, while `TValue.From<Integer>(i).AsExtended` is 200+ times slower.

Comment: Nice.  I immediately thought of .NET extension methods but I didn't know Delphi had this feature... XE3+ only, it looks like?

Comment: Yes, XE3 only, handy but with some restrictions. I will add to the answer.

Comment: Ah yes, I remember those forum threads well. Pronouncements from the Church of Veltology.

Comment: Helper function syntax was introduced in Delphi for .NET in 2003. The syntax may have been carried over to the Win32 compiler in the Delphi 2005 release, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @dthorpe, record helpers and class helpers came in Delphi-2005, but the last addition with record helpers for intrinsic types came in XE3. It is a move to introduce rooted types.

Comment: @LURD record helpers and class helpers were created for Delphi .NET released in 2003. The syntax was created to allow us to "attach" methods on CLR types so that legacy Delphi source code would see the method names it expected while still using native CLR types. Patents applied for in 2000.

Comment: @LURD Thanks for your update. I think that the `ToDouble` helper from XE4 is the best answer in the long term. I have to say that I was surprised to find out that the language offers no help at all with this.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you use a simple function:

```
function IntToDouble(const AInt: Integer): Double;
begin
  Result := AInt;
end;


Format('Theoretical peak scaling %6.2f', [IntToDouble(ThreadCount)]);
```

Comment: Well, this is certainly a clean approach. I was hoping for something built into the language or perhaps the RTL. It seems surprising that there would not be such a thing. Converting between types is such an fundamental task.

Comment: Converting between types that are compatible requires no code, so it's simple to use a typecast to tell the compiler you want to view this as that. But converting between incompatible types requires runtime support to do the heavy lifting. Why burden the language with automatic hidden conversions when explicit conversions are as performant and clearer as to what is actually happening? Variants have proven that (Delphi) people don't like automatic hidden data conversions.

Comment: @dthorpe I don't want automatic hidden conversions. I think I want an explicit conversion. But I cannot find one.

Comment: @dthorpe It is explicit. It is an explicit multiplication. Not an explicit conversion.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I use '+0.0' as opposed to '*1.0', but as you say, this is not an explicit conversion.

Comment: @StefanGlienke, I thought about it. inline is not guaranteed to be effective. And the compilers are good at producing optimized code.

Answer (score 3):

You could also do something like this:

```
Format('Theoretical peak scaling %3d.00', [ThreadCount])
```

Integer ThreadCount is never going to have any fractional portion, so it would be just as accurate to put the fractional zeros in the string and take the data as integer. ;>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ToExtended` function provided by the integer type

```
Format('Theoretical peak scaling %6.2f', [ThreadCount.ToExtended])
```